# vscode change javascript indent size

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm wondering if there is a way to change the indent size when formatting javascript in VSCode.

I found this
[git commit](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/commit/a6b346ccffd85af5f74ee0c65a229ec72f63df7c) that adds quite a few formatting options for JS but I don't see any ability to change indent size.

Anyone know of a way to do this?

--Edit--

I have already tried to change the indent size at the bottom of the editor.
[Toolbar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxEnm.png) (can't embed images yet...)

I have also tried changing the detect indentation setting.
`"editor.detectIndentation": false`

But when I format it still uses two spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [visual studio code change indentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174207/visual-studio-code-change-indentation)

Comment: @manu I don't think it is. I looked at that and have already tried the solution there. Thank you for the link though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a plugin called JS-CSS-HTML Formatter. It does exactly that, the ability to change editor settings for different file types.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter

Comment: This does solve the problem. Thank you! I'm hoping there is a built in way to do this.

Comment: @brandonbanks if it has solved your issue could you please accept this as the correct answer? Cheers!