# How do I stop VSCode auto formatting from deleting spaces inside parentheses?

Tags: visual-studio-code

for example, when I write

```
foo( bar ){}
```

it will be formatted to

```
foo(bar){}
```

how do I make it keep the 2 spaces?

Edit:
This is a different question from [How to change indentation in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174207)

Comment: @JustLearning The above link is an entirely different question.

Answer (score 3):

Putting

```
 "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyParenthesis": true
```

in the settings json solved the problem.