# VS Code Removing Spaces Inside Parenthesis

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, if I type:

```
function fname( $var ) {
}
```

It gets converted to:

```
function fname($var) {
}
```

Is there a setting that will work for ALL languages, like:

```
"format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyParentheses": false
```

Here are my relevant VS Code settings:

```
{
    "[js]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[php]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client",
        "format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false
        "editor.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true
    },
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.find.loop": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "none",
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.trimAutoWhitespace": true
}
```

Please note: I know if I remove "editor.formatOnSave": true, it'll stop, but I don't want to do that since I'll lose all my other formatting. I need a solution that works with "editor.formatOnSave": true.

Comment: If you are using prettier, you should be aware that prettier is an *opinionated* formatter and you have limited configuration options (i.e. if you don't like it you may not be able to change it).

Comment: It's doing it for all my languages, not just JavaScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop VSCode auto formatting from deleting spaces inside parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441149/how-do-i-stop-vscode-auto-formatting-from-deleting-spaces-inside-parentheses)