# changing vscode indentation format

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change the indentation style format in Visual Studio Code.
I searched but I only find how to change tab sizes .

In other words:

My code :

```
if    (..)   {
    }
```

After formatting with visual code

```
if(..)
{
}
```

While I expect

```
if(..){
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change indentation in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174207/how-to-change-indentation-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: The spaces and the bracket style are 2 separate settings that are *not* considered to be part of "indentation". It's going to depend on the language formatter you are using. Is this C++? Also, I removed [visual studio] tag as that is completely different from [visual-studio-code].