# How can I change the tab size of all my written VS Code?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I have started working with someone else on VS Code and they are using a tab size of 4 while I use 2. I have changed mine to 4 as well now but my already written code has a tab size of 2 but I would like to change all of it to 4 without manually go through all the code.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: are you inserting tabs or spaces? Select 2 spaces, **Select All Occurrences**, type 4 spaces, or use a document formatter

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174207/how-to-change-indentation-in-visual-studio-code?rq=1

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174207/how-to-change-indentation-in-visual-studio-code
You can change the tab indent size in vs code and format your project again.

Answer (score 1):

You can select all the code and press tab manually of what tab size you want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The solution for your problem is very simple just

> Press `Ctrl+F` in vs-code and

> Then in the find section type `\t` then

> In the replace section type `\t\t`

Yay! your work is done

Hope it helped :)