# Changing VSCode-Vim Indent to 4 spaces

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscodevim

I am using VSCode's  Vim extension and it seems like the tabs are set to two spaces, but I want to change this because I work mostly in Python, which uses 4 spaces. I have found several posts/articles about changing tab spacings in Vim, but at first glance they don't seem wholly applicable since this is a VS-Code extension. I have one pre-existing mapping that I have added below.

**Current Key Remap**

```
    "vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
        {
            "before": ["j", "j"],
            "after": ["<Esc>"]
        }
    ],
```

The structure should follow similar to that above, but ideally I would want my normal mode tabbing to be something like `shift >  >` (which is the default) but with 4 spaces instead of whatever it currently is.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Try running: `:set noexpandtab` as per [this wiki page](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces).

I was having the same issue, specifically `[tab]` would add tabs, but the `o` command in Normal Mode would insert spaces on the new line. Seems to be working all around.

#### VSCode Settings

I would like to post my indent and tab settings so people can compare incase that's the problem as well. Please forgive my screenshots of the settings UI, I cannot be bothered going through all that JSON.

[image: Auto Indent Settings]

[image: Detect Indentation Settings]

[image: Insert Spaces Settings]

[image: Tab Size Settings]

Please let me know if I missed any relevant ones in the comments.

#### Or, the opposite:

It may be of use to folks who are trying to do the opposite, i.e., go from tabs to spaces, that they should use `:set expandtab`.

Comment: Nope, with these settings, vim still autoindents (the `=`key`) using 2 spaces.

Answer (score -1):

I think you just have to modify in Visual Studio Code settings and not in the Vim settings.

See the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174207/how-to-change-indentation-in-visual-studio-code) that resume the way to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve it. The editor is able to detect that the spaces are set to 4 and that Python is the language being used. Moreover, I can turn vim off and just tab like normal.