# VS Code no longer shows errors

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm new to the coding world. Was using VS code to learn Java without any issue up till now. But all of a sudden, it doesn't underline errors (Syntax or logical) any more. I tried googling for help, but couldn't resolve the matter.

[image: No Errors Underlined]

Comment: Instead of editing your question, post your solution as an answer instead, and don't put [Solved] in the title.

Comment: Got it. New to coding and stackoverflow. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174207/how-to-change-indentation-in-visual-studio-code) post shows how to adjust the required settings. Courtasy to [epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello).

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted an answer on behalf of the question author, to move it to the answer space)*.

Update: The matter is resolved. Cleaned the workspace cache. Things are working like before.