# VS Code - How to change the line spacing

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

This is how my code looks like in VS code. Please note the small yellow marking I made in the 3rd line. [My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow5av.png)

I want to reduce that space (again please check small yellow marking in the 3rd line).
[Tutorial code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofHNU.png)

Basically, I want to reduce the size of whitespace allocated to each code block. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Edit: As a new user, I cant embed images to the post itself. Appreciate if someone can edit my post to display the images themselves instead of a link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174207/how-to-change-indentation-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Tool -> options -> text editor.  Once there, pick the language (in this case html) and then select the arrow to open up the drop down and select Tabs - you have the options of how many spaces / tabs you want to use in there