I set a file to indentation spaces 1, but it keeps opening with indentation space 2
All files I create in Visual Studio Code version:
Version: 1.95.3 (user setup)
Commit: f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813
Date: 2024-11-13T14:50:04.152Z
Electron: 32.2.1
ElectronBuildId: 10427718
Chromium: 128.0.6613.186
Node.js: 20.18.0
V8: 12.8.374.38-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631

open with space indentation 1 (my preferred indentation):

However, one of the files opens with space indentation 2 by default:

What is this setting on the file which opens it with default space indentation 2, while all other files open with space indentation 1? What am I doing wrong?
I tried changing the space indentaiton to 1 and then pressing Ctrl+S:

However, when I close it, I expect the setting to be saved, but it reopens with space indentation 2 and still works fine. Why does this file open with default space indentation 2 while others open with default space indentation 1? My file is overriding default settings by default.
 I try rewriting it using the Clipboard, but it still happens. I permanently deleted the original file while keeping its contents on the Clipboard, and then paste it in a new file, but it still happens. I had manually rewritten it, but it still is like that. Is it because of the nested conditionals?
Difference
≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈
How to change indentation in Visual Studio Code? has it with 8 spaces on all his files, but it happens on only one file for me.
ᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠ

"I am learning the Python programming language"  The indentation is a pretty important part of programming in Python.  But the "how much" indentation  has nothing to do with programming.

It is different because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174207/how-to-change-indentation-in-visual-studio-code 's asker has it opening with 8 spaces on ALL his files, but for me, it happens on only ONE file.

Thank you for the constructive criticism.

As an aside, 1-space indentation feels far too little. Most people use 4 spaces. With only 1 space, you may have difficulty seeing the structure of your code once you start writing larger programs.

In Scratch (scratch.mit.edu), a C block looks like it indents blocks inside it by 1, not 4.

It is an indentation setting where that line was indented with 2 spaces. The nested conditionals I think override the settings, but is that really true?

In Scratch (scratch.mit.edu), a C block looks like it indents blocks inside it by 1, not 4 - that has nothing to do with python indentation. pep8[https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/] recommends 4 spaces. Scratch uses much more visual guides to highlight indentation/nesting so it doesn't need much indentation to make visually clear how the program is structured

@FlyingTeller the file is still indented by 1 space because those are the contents of the file, but the problem is that VSCode thinks indentation for that file is 2 spaces (see the status bar at bottom-right) and because of this, it only shows one vertical bar next to that line, implying it's got 1 level of indentation, when in fact it's 2.

The link https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/] is broken.

@Pierre2001 it's just that it has an extraneous ] at the end. The correct link is https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/ . It is advisable to follow those guidelines because at least 90% of all the world's Python programmers follow those guidelines, and if you ever start publishing your own code or writing as part of a team at work, your code would look strange to most colleagues/collaborators if it had an indentation of 1 space.

While I cannot say why it works on some files, but not others, there is a note in the documentation of Visual Studio Code that is of relevance here:

Note: VS Code auto-detection checks for indentations of 2, 4, 6 or 8 spaces. If your file uses a different number of spaces, the indentation may not be correctly detected. For example, if your convention is to indent with 3 spaces, you may want to turn off editor.detectIndentation and explicitly set the tab size to 3.

So I would tell you to try to disable the detectIndentation feature in your user settings. In the Settings menu, search the “detectindentation” keyword.
Might be that for your other files Visual Studio Code did not run the detection at all (file too short maybe) or could determine indentation correctly even though it should not be able to detect indentation of 1 according to the documentation.

That's a great find! It's also highly disappointing that VS Code only supports indentations in multiples of 2. That's an arbitrary limitation, especially when it applies in a language-independent way, and there is at least one language I know of (Ada) which has an official guideline recommending indentation of 3 spaces. Also, at a previous employer I worked in a team that had a C project code style with 3-space indentation, and I can say that it worked very well.
