# Visual Studio Code - Convert spaces to tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs, spaces

I have both TypeScript and HTML files in my project, in both files tabs are converted to spaces.

I want to turn the auto-conversion off and make sure that my project has only tabs.

Edit:

With this setting it seems to work in HTML files but not in TypeScript files.

```json
{
  "editor.insertSpaces": false
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert tabs to spaces and vice versa in an existing file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33974681/how-can-i-convert-tabs-to-spaces-and-vice-versa-in-an-existing-file)

Answer (score 450, accepted):

There are 3 options in `.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
// The number of spaces a tab is equal to.
"editor.tabSize": 4,

// Insert spaces when pressing Tab.
"editor.insertSpaces": true,

// When opening a file, `editor.tabSize` and `editor.insertSpaces` will be detected based on the file contents.
"editor.detectIndentation": true
```

`editor.detectIndentation` detects it from your file, you have to disable it.
If it didn't help, check that you have no settings with higher priority.
For example when you save it to User settings it could be overwritten by Workspace settings which are in your project folder.

***Update:***

To access these settings, you can open **File** » **Preferences** » **Settings**, click the *Manage* cog icon at the bottom left, or use the keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>**CTRL**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**,**</kbd> *(Windows, Linux)*

<kbd>**⌘**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**,**</kbd> *(Mac)*

***Update:***

Now you have an alternative to editing those options manually. 
 Click on selector **Spaces:4** at the bottom-right of the editor:
[image: Ln44, Col . [Spaces:4] . UTF-8 with BOM . CTRLF . HTML . :)]

**EDIT:**

To convert existing indentation from spaces to tabs hit <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**Shift**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**P**</kbd> and type:

```
>Convert indentation to Tabs
```

This will change the indentation for your document based on the defined settings to Tabs.

Comment: How do I run this command for all files in my workspace.

Comment: how do I do `>Convert indentation to Tabs` permanently for all my files and projects in VSCode?

Comment: @FäridAlijani, @ VijenderKumar I don't think it is possible using VS Code

Comment: @VijenderKumar see [How can I convert indentation between spaces and tabs for all files in a workspace in a single action?](/q/51068247/11107541)

Answer (score 186):

To change tab settings, click the text area right to the Ln/Col text in the status bar on the bottom right of vscode window.

The name can be `Tab Size` or `Spaces`.

A menu will pop up with all available actions and settings.

[image]

Comment: For me, this only changes these settings for the particular file I'm currently viewing. The other files in the project keep their old settings. How would you set it universally?

Comment: I usually replace all my files at once, if I need to, by doing a project search for the simple regex ` {4}` and replace with \t (for tabs). Usually also glance over the matches to make sure nothing will break like multi-line string literals, etc. Obviously apply these settings so that your new indentations are the desired characters, too!

Answer (score 59):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, then *"Convert Indentation to Tabs"*

Comment: Is it possible to do this for a selection and not the whole file?

Comment: is it possible to do this for a whole repo and not just one file?

Comment: @dbrane Yes. If you highlight a block of code in a file, the conversion applies just within the selection. Btw, on Mac the key combo is ⌥ + P (alt/option + P).

Answer (score 37):

## If you want to use tabs instead of spaces

### Try this:

1. Go to **`File`** ➤ **`Preferences`** ➤ **`Settings`** or just press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> **+** <kbd>**,**</kbd>
2. In the **Search settings** bar on top insert `editor.insertSpaces`
3. You will see something like this: **Editor: Insert Spaces** and it will be probably checked. Just uncheck it as show in image below

[image: Editor: Insert Spaces]

4. Reload **Visual Studio Code** (Press **`F1`** ➤ type `reload window` ➤ press <kbd>**Enter**</kbd>)

---

### If it doesn't worked try this:

It's probably because of installed plugin **JS-CSS-HTML Formatter**

*(You can check it by going to **`File`** ➤ **`Preferences`** ➤ **`Extensions`** or just pressing <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> **+** <kbd>**Shift**</kbd> **+** <kbd>**X**</kbd>, in the **Enabled** list you will find **JS-CSS-HTML Formatter**)*

If so you can modify this plugin:

1. Press <kbd>**F1**</kbd> ➤ type `Formatter config` ➤ press <kbd>**Enter**</kbd> (it will open the file *`formatter.json`*)
2. Modify the file like this:

```
 4|    "indent_size": 1,
 5|    "indent_char": "\t"
——|
24|    "indent_size": 1,
25|    "indentCharacter": "\t",
26|    "indent_char": "\t",
——|
34|    "indent_size": 1,
35|    "indent_char": "\t",
36|    "indent_character": "\t"
```

3. Save it (Go to **`File`** ➤ **`Save`** or just press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> **+** <kbd>**S**</kbd>)
4. Reload **Visual Studio Code** (Press <kbd>**F1**</kbd> ➤ type `reload window` ➤ press <kbd>**Enter**</kbd>)

Comment: If you want spaces instead of tabs, modify `formatter.json` file: put one _space_ in any quotation mark instead of `\t` (So `"\t"` became `" "`), and put *4* where you see *1*. So you come might be like this
 `"indent_size": 4,
"indent_char": " "
"indent_size": 4,
"indentCharacter": " ",
"indent_char": " ",
"indent_size": 4,
"indent_char": " ",
"indent_character": " "`

Comment: The RELOAD WINDOW step was what I was missing. Frustrating to have gone the process of checking boxes and fiddling with settings 3 times for no changes to take, when all I had to do was reload window. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Reloading VS Code did the trick

Comment: thank you. The only answer, describing how to do it.

Answer (score 10):

Below settings are worked well for me,

```
"editor.insertSpaces": false,
"editor.formatOnSave": true, // only if you want auto fomattting on saving the file
"editor.detectIndentation": false
```

Above settings will reflect and applied to every files. You don't need to indent/format every file manually.

Answer (score 10):

Check this from official vscode setting:

```
// Controls whether `editor.tabSize#` and `#editor.insertSpaces` will be automatically detected when a file is opened based on the file contents.
"editor.detectIndentation": true,

// The number of spaces a tab is equal to. This setting is overridden based on the file contents when `editor.detectIndentation` is on.
"editor.tabSize": 4,

// Config the editor that making the "space" instead of "tab"
"editor.insertSpaces": true,

// Configure editor settings to be overridden for [html] language.
"[html]": {
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.autoIndent": false
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In my case, the problem was **JS-CSS-HTML Formatter** extension installed after january update. The default `indent_char` property is space. I uninstalled it and the weird behavior stops.

Comment: Oh yes, this is was the actual issue for me. spend a lot of time tinkering around setting in VS code. finally disabling this extension solved the problem.

Answer (score 9):

1. Highlight your Code (in file)
2. Click Tab Size in bottom righthand corner of application window
   [image: Tab Size in bottom righthand corner of application window image]
3. Select the appropriate Convert Indentation to Tabs
   [image: Select the appropriate Convert Indentation to Tabs image]

Answer (score 6):

*File* -> *Preferences* -> *Settings* or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> and search for *spaces*, then just deactivate this option:

[image]

I had to reopen the file so the changes would take effect.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change tabs to spaces in a lot of files, but don't want to open them individually, I have found that it works equally as well to just use the **Find and Replace** option from the left-most tools bar.

In the first box (`Find`), copy and paste a tab from the source code.

In the second box (`Replace`), enter the number of spaces that you wish to use (i.e. 2 or 4).

If you press the `...` button, you can specify directories to include or ignore (i.e. `src/Data/Json`).

Finally, inspect the result preview and press **Replace All**. All files in the workspace may be affected.

Answer (score 2):

Set this to `false` if you are using `.sass` files and it's giving you the `Expected tabs, was spaces` error:

```json
"editor.detectIndentation": false
```

... then select your block of code and indent it by pressing the `tab` key and indent it back by pressing the `shift + tab` key.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was about unchecking

**Prettier: Use Tabs**

on VSCode settings

Answer (score -2):

```
{
  "editor.insertSpaces": true
}
```

`True` works for me.