# Prevent Visual Studio Code from replacing tabs with spaces on save

Tags: visual-studio-code

My problem is not present while editing a file, like here: [Spaces to tabs in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814642/spaces-to-tabs-in-visual-studio-code)

VSC converts all tabs to spaces when I **save** the file. How could I stop that stupid behavior?

This are my actual user settings:

```
{
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false
}
```

Further informations:

```
 "editor.formatOnSave": false
```

Comment: Do you have extensions installed / what file type does this happen with? Are those all your settings, or do you also have `editor.formatOnSave` enabled for instance?

Comment: That's the hint! Thank you. I'll update my Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an extension which overrides the default behaviour:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter

Answer (score 5):

Wish I understood more about what's happening here, but in my case, what finally worked (for now) was unchecking "Editor: Insert Spaces" in my user prefs. Without this, disabling `Save on Format` didn't seem to help. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

[image: screenshot of the "Editor: Insert Spaces" setting, unchecked]