# How to execute command across multiple files in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to optimize my typescript code by running some commands (e.g. `resolve.organizeImports` that comes with TS Hero plugin) in all of my typescript (.ts) files.

Doing this file by file can be quite tiresome and time consuming. Is there an easy way of doing this sort of 'bulk' execute?

Comment: Damn, did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: If anyone is interested, here is a very hacky way I achieved this: https://github.com/dwjohnston/formatallfilesinworkspace

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have written the extension [Command on All Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.commandOnAllFiles). It is a modification of the extension [Format All Files in Workspace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexr00.formatallfilesinworkspace) by Alex Ross.

You can configure multiple commands that you want to run on all files and configure to which files it should apply. You can override the `includeFileExtensions` and `excludeFolders` setting per command.

If you use [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) by ryuta46 you can create a sequence of commands that you want to apply to each file. (Why recreate what already is implemented) For an example see the extension page.

For the `organizeImports` from the **TS Hero** plugin you can have this configuration

`settings.json`

```json
  "commandOnAllFiles.commands": {
    "TS Hero: Organize Imports": {
      "command": "typescriptHero.imports.organize",
      "includeFileExtensions": [".ts"]
    }
  }
```

`keybindings.json`

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i o", // or any other key combo
    "command": "commandOnAllFiles.applyOnWorkspace",
    "args": ["TS Hero: Organize Imports"]
  }
```

For version 0.1.0 of the extension only the method of the keybinding is implemented to supply the argument to the `commandOnAllFiles.applyOnWorkspace` command. In the next release it can be done from the Command Palette.