# How can I convert indentation between spaces and tabs for all files in a workspace in a single action?

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation

How can I use VS Code's **Convert Indentation To Spaces** or **Convert Indentation to Tabs** commands on all the files in my workspace in a single action instead of using the command for each file?

Comment: Somewhat related but not duplicates: [Replace whitespaces with tabs in linux](/q/1424126). And on superuser: [How to replace multiple spaces by one tab](https://superuser.com/q/241018/1749748)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a UNIX system, you can do this via command line using a modified version of this: `git ls-files | command grep -E '*.ts$' | awk '{print "expand --tabs=4 --first-only", $0, " > /tmp/e; mv /tmp/e ", $0}' | sh`, which lists all files tracked in the git repo for the current working directory, filters for files with the `.ts` extension, and then uses `awk` and [`expand`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expand_(Unix)) to replace leading indentation of a tabs to a specified number of spaces.

To go from spaces to tabs, use the [`unexpand`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unexpand) command instead.

If you're not working with a git repo, you can replace `git ls-files` with `find -type f` (the advantage of `git ls-files` is that it won't touch anything that's not tracked).

Just change the regular expression in the grep filter to whatever you need.

The command replaces leading groups of 4 spaces with tab characters. Just change the `--tabs` argument to the `unexpand` command with whatever number of spaces your indentation is.

---

If you want a VS Code way of doing it, you can use [rioV8](/users/9938317)'s extension: [Command on All Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.commandOnAllFiles) <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup> (use the `editor.action.indentationToTabs` or `editor.action.indentationToSpaces` command). I found this from this Q&A: [How to execute command across multiple files in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47652442/11107541).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/76386322/11107541.