# Visual Studio Code - Convert tabs to spaces for all files in folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know I can manually replace tabs to spaces like this:

1. `F1`,
2. `indentationToSpaces`
3. `Enter`.

Is there a way to do this for all files in a folder (+ files in subfolders)?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11094620/13944524

Comment: Kind of, Thx! is there also a way to do this via VSC?

Comment: you can use extension [Command on All Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.commandOnAllFiles)

Comment: @rioV8 it is unclear how to use it. Their example is bad.

Comment: with the key binding dialog you can find the VSC command that is mapped to a Command Palette command

Comment: 1400 installs does not mean that they understood it, the probably uninstalled it again like me. The extension does not work. I press F1 and write "commandOnAllFiles" but it says "no matching commands"

Comment: in the Command Palette you need to search for `Apply 1 or more commands to all files in the Workspace`, but it does not work from the Command Palette because it needs a lot of arguments in the settings file. The number on the page is the number of people USING the extension

Comment: Ok how am I supposed to know that I need to write `Apply 1 or more commands to all files in the Workspace` in the command pallette? This is described nowhere. There are missing basic informations. And if it does not work from the command pallette, then how on earth does it work?

Comment: Ok so I figured out I have to add a hotkey instead, but it does not execute my intendation to space command... a review also says that it does not work, he tried the same.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/51068247/11107541

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I think, you are looking for an extension.
But my answer is a litle trick - using the `global replacer` with regex:

**We change step by step to save the amount of indentation** and replace `tabs` only in the start of line.

[image]

The below snippet shows replace step by step,`s` presents `one space`
and `_` precents `one tab`:

```js
test = '_____Text__'
for(let i=0; i < 7; i++){
  test = test.replace(/^([ ]*)(_)/, "$1 ")
  console.log( 'step', i, test.replace(/[ ]/g, 's'))
}
```

You may use two spaces instead one.

But this solution has **1 issue** - after replace you must update regexp (for example: add and remove space) for activate this button again

[image]

So at the end steps look like:

1. fill: `regexp`, `replace`, `files to include`
2. click `replace`
3. update `regexp`
   or click **twice** on one of this buttons: [image]
4. repeat from `step 2` some times