# How can I reindent all files in a workspace at once in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation, auto-indent

I'd like to reindent all files in a VS Code project, after changing indentation configuration. I can perfectly reindent a single file by opening it and running the *Reindent Lines* command. But I don't want to do that for every file in the project, as there are to many.

Is there a way to convert indentation in a whole project, e.g. by applying *Reindent Lines* to folders or multiple files at once?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rioV8](/users/9938317)'s extension: [Command on All Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.commandOnAllFiles) <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>.

I found this from this Q&A: [How to execute command across multiple files in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47652442/11107541).

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, it worked. A little weird, that it visually opens each file, but it does the job.