# VSCode not respecting `[yaml]: editor.tabSize` in all files. Some 2-space indentation, some 4-space indentation

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm having difficulty with tab size in VSCode. For some YAML files I'm getting 2-space indentation while others are getting 4-space indentation. I'd like to always use 2-space indentation.

The below images show what the files look like when open in VSCode. Note that the vertical lines indicating indentation depth are different. This points to VSCode recognizing the indentation differently for the two files.

Some look like this:

[image]

Some look like this:

[image]

The yaml-specific settings in my user settings are:

```json
    "yaml.completion": false,
    "yaml.format.enable": true,
    "[yaml]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.vscode-yaml",
        "editor.tabSize": 2
    },
```

It appears to me that VSCode is actually recognizing the different indentation in the two files and is respecting that rather than respecting my `tabSize: 2` setting. Does anyone know how to get 2 spaces to be used for all YAML files?

Comment: Is it possible you created the 4-space files before you set that setting? Or do they come from elsewhere? You might just need to reindent them.

Comment: Related to the above point on reindentation: [In VS Code, How do I format a document (.cpp) so that it converts indentation with N spaces to indentation with M spaces?](/q/75954165/11107541)

Comment: You're right, they were created by someone else. I redid the indentation, though. When I saved the file it reindented to 4-space indentation.

Comment: hm. what if you redo the indentation and then close that editor tab and then reopen the file and try saving then? or restart VS Code?

Comment: @user that actually does fix the problem for one file. I'd like them all to reformat to 2 spaces, but maybe I'll just have to script that.

Comment: see [How to execute command across multiple files in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47652442/11107541)

Comment: Thanks @user, this looks handy. I'll give it a shot for some other stuff. Some language you used, though, led me to the solution. I turned off "detect indentation" and it fixed my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some language in the comments led me to the solution. There is a setting to "detect indentation". Disabling that setting made VSCode respect my indentation settings.

The setting to disable is `Editor: Detect Indentation`.

Answer (score 1):

I found that my settings.json had prettier.tabWidth and it looked out of sync with tabSize which is used elsewhere. So on a whim I changed it to prettier.tabSize, restarted VS Code, and that solved it for me.

```
{
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    },
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
    "[vue]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "Vue.volar"
    },
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "off",
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "prettier.tabSize": 4,
    "[jsonc]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "vetur.format.options.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.indentSize": "tabSize",
    "editor.detectIndentation": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Remove the line `"prettier.tabWidth": 4` works for me!