# How can I make folding regions folded by default in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to close all closable code segments of some kind in VS Code?

For example I want all my style property code segments to be closed by default and only open them when they are hovered. Is this possible? They get extremely huge and make a component unreadable.

Comment: This might be possible but you need to show what a code segment you are interested in folding looks like to help.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of (without using extensions). But you can get pretty close.

You can fold (collapse) all folding regions in an editor by using the `Fold All` command in the command palette, or whatever keyboard shortcut that command is bound to by default. On Windows and Linux, it's bound to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>cltr</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>. I assume that on macOS, you just switch <kbd>ctrl</kbd> in the previous shortcut with <kbd>cmd</kbd>. VS Code remembers things about the workspace state like which folding regions are folded or not folded. It will recall that info when reopening a closed editor tab, or reopening the workspace.

---

If you're opening to trying extensions, try [@rioV8](/users/9938317)'s [`rioj7.commandOnAllFiles`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.commandOnAllFiles) <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup> (see also [How to execute command across multiple files in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47652442/11107541)), where usage might look something like this:

settings.json:

```json
  "commandOnAllFiles.commands": {
    "Fold All Folding Regions": {
      "command": "editor.foldAll"
    }
  }
```

keybindings.json:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i o", // or any other key combo
    "command": "commandOnAllFiles.applyOnWorkspace",
    "args": ["Fold All Folding Regions"]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Mate! Will try that out and let you know