# How can I configure all new files to use tab indention instead of spaces by default?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs, settings

Currently, whenever I create a new file (no matter the file type) it starts out using spaces for indention.  I always have to click and convert to tabs.

How can I configure **all** new files to use tabs by default to avoid this step?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert tabs to spaces and vice versa in an existing file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33974681/how-can-i-convert-tabs-to-spaces-and-vice-versa-in-an-existing-file)

Comment: @starball as the question clearly states, this issue relates to *new* files and defaults, not converting existing files. See the accepted answer below and comments indicating this question and answer are helpful. Not a duplicate of the suggested answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following in whichever settings file makes sense for you (your user settings.json, or a .vscode/settings.json, or a .code-workspace file):

```json
"editor.insertSpaces": false
```

You can change this setting on a per-file-type basis like so:

```json
"[json]": {"editor.insertSpaces": true},
"[javascript]": {"editor.insertSpaces": false}
```

To change the indentation for an existing file, use the `Convert Indentation to Tabs` command.

You can also use `editor.detectIndentation` to change whether VS Code should try to detect what indentation a file is already using to follow it.

Comment: Been looking for this forever, tnx!