# How to make indentation being indentation and not 4 space in Makefile on VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code, makefile, indentation

I have this makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu99 -pthread
EXAMPLES=fibs fauxgrep fauxgrep-mt fhistogram fhistogram-mt

.PHONY: all test clean ../src.zip

all: $(TESTS) $(EXAMPLES)

job_queue.o: job_queue.c job_queue.h
    $(CC) -c job_queue.c $(CFLAGS)

%: %.c job_queue.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

test: $(TESTS)
    @set e; for test in $(TESTS); do echo ./$$test; ./$$test; done
    
test_file: test_%_%.c
    $(CC) -o test_%_% $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(TESTS) $(EXAMPLES) *.o core

../src.zip:
    make clean
    cd .. && zip src.zip -r src
```

When I try to run `make test_file`i get error `Makefile:19: *** missing separator.  Stop.`. I have added my own code in test_file command. I can see, when highlighting the different lines, that VSC registers the code lines provided in clean command as indentation, but when I use tab, I get 4 spaces instead in the test_file command.

[image]

I have unchecked the setting **Editor: Insert Spaces** but I still get 4 spaces, when using tab. How do I make it be indentation instead of 4 spaces?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert tabs to spaces and vice versa in an existing file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33974681/how-can-i-convert-tabs-to-spaces-and-vice-versa-in-an-existing-file)